# Typecript - How to send union strings as enum?

Tags: typescript

The following code does not compile ([https://www.typescriptlang.org/play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEElQYwQwOwOQBdoAt4HMCmoCWKkB7UAIxwFE4BXAWwCYBYAKC2ptEtoEZQBvZ0KACCoALygEMBABoBoAEJiJJGcwC%20zZiFAwqRUNjhYATjCRYAJqQCeoJKlzGrAG1wlTx20ULPQAWmh4ZDRMHHxmVloONjo%20ORFxSVUmQUVElVkmDSYtMF19QxMzSxs7BydQV3cYTztCH39AxBQodDhsPCRmJGsABxwAVThcQjglJNAAH2UETSYLLChnGpwAMyo4KCQRsdWuAAosAC5o7gBKE4A3QlwLOb39znoAOiEz0G0LQiwAZ1A4QgtQg0Xq4ZxYZgPJLvT7fP4AoEgsFYIA)):

```js
// I can't change it to be Enum2
enum Enum1 {
  A = 'a',
  B = 'b',
}

// auto generated by third library tool - can't change it
enum Enum2 {
  A = 'a',
  B = 'b',
}

// auto generated by third library tool - can't change it
type Union = 'a' | 'b'

declare function f1(e: Enum1): void

// Argument of type 'Enum2.A' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Enum1'.(2345)
f1(Enum2.A) // does not compile
f1('a') // does not compile
```

Error:

> TS2345: Argument of type 'HardhatPodStartedDto[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<HardhatPodStarted[]>'

What can I do to solve the compilation error?

- I can't change Enum1, Enum2, Union.

Comment: I have a strong suspicion there are more constraints than you've listed. For instance, I'm guessing the code inside `f1` does something with `e`, and that may well influence the suggestions you're given. But right now, we don't have a lot to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you haven't said you can't change is the function, so:

```typescript
declare function f1(e: Union): void
//                     ^^^^^
```

Both of your examples then work: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEElQYwQwOwOQBdoAt4HMCmoCWKkB7UAIxwFE4BXAWwCYBYAKC2ptEtoEZQBvZ0KACCoALygEMBABoBoAEJiJJGcwC+zZiFAwqRUNjhYATjCRYAJqQCeoJKlzGrAG1wlTx20ULPQAWmh4ZDRMHHxmVloONjo+ORFxSVUmQUVElVkmDSYtMF19QxMzSxs7BydQV3cYTztCH39AxBQodDhsPCRmJGsABxwAVThcQjglJNAAH2UETSYLLChnGpwAMyo4KCQRsdWuAAosAC5QIZ2AShOAN0JcCzm9-c56ADohc9BtC0IsAGdQOCEFqEGi9XDOLDMR5JD5fH7-QHA0HgrBAA)

**If** the implementaton of `f1` needs to convert from `Union` to `Enum1` or `Enum2`, there's really no shortcut for it. You can readily create a function, though:

```typescript
const unionToEnum1 = (u: Union): Enum1 => {
    switch (u) {
        case "a":
            return Enum1.A;
        case "b":
            return Enum1.B;
        default:
            throw new Error(`Unexpected 'Union' value "${u}"`);
    }
};
```

And/or similar for `Enum2`.

And/or a compile-time conversion for those situations where one will work:

```typescript
type UnionToEnum1<U extends Union> =
      U extends "a" ? Enum1.A
    : U extends "b" ? Enum1.B
    : never;
```